# How to pass a variable as a parameter to cypher query (neo4j)

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, cypher

I would like to pass a variable (values from request body) as a parameter to the cypher query but i don´t know if (and how) this is possible. 
I´ve tried few things and a "normal" cypher query with hardcoded string parameter is working perfectly, but when I want to pass the variable as a parameter, I´ll get an error *Structure(127, [[object Object]])*.
I´m on Neo4j 3.1. in combination with a node.js-server which builds the cypher queries.

This is a snippet..

```
var user_firstname = req.body.firstname;
var user_lastname = req.body.lastname;
var user_city = req.body.city;
session
    .run("CREATE (n:Person {firstname: {firstname}, lastname: {lastname}, city: {city}})", 
      { firstname: user_firstname, 
        lastname: user_lastname, 
        city: user_city })
```

Thanks in advance for your help, cheers!

Comment: Are all your `user_*` variables strings, or are some of them objects?

Comment: no, they´re all strings (some of them are ints..)

Comment: Just to be sure -- are you saying that because that is the schema you expect, or have you actually verified that the response data conforms to the schema?

Comment: aaaaaah... thanks so much! your answer was a kind of advice for me! I´ve made a post with (name, lastname, city...) but the pattern expected inside the query is (FIRSTname, lastname, city...) ;) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Neo4j 3.1 I believe [parameter syntax was changed](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/). Try using $ before the parameter instead of encasing it in brackets. See if this query will work instead:

```
CREATE (n:Person {firstname: $firstname, lastname: $lastname, city: $city})
```

Comment: This should not be a problem, as the old syntax is only deprecated, but still supported - see the related [issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/7558): "Note: The old syntax is not going away for a long time"

Comment: thanks for this, works also perfectly and looks a bit clearer

Comment: Good to know the old syntax will stick around for a bit. Is there something else in play here that prevented the old approach from working?